# Why is lodash _.sample function returning type number[] | undefined

Tags: typescript, lodash

Example 1

```
const myNumber = _.sample([1, 2, 3]);
// Expected type: number
// Actual type: number
```

Example 2

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3]
const myNumber = _.sample(arr);
// Expected type: number
// Actual type: number | undefined
```

Why is Typescript giving the type `number | undefined` in the second case, but not the first case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because in one case the length of the array is known, and in the other it is not. If the length might be 0, then `undefined` is a possible output.

When you do `const arr = [1, 2, 3]`, the type on `arr` is `number[]`. That means it's an array of numbers which can grow and shrink. You and I can see that it's not going to shrink to 0-length before the next line, but the type information doesn't include that knowledge. So when it gets passed into sample, the types say that undefined is a possible result.

When you create and use the array in the exact same spot, as in `_.sample([1, 2, 3]);`, typescript is able to assume a stricter type because it knows how it is being used. The type is inferred to be `[number, number, number]`, ie a tuple of length 3, and therefore an element will definitely be returned.

If you want to make this happen with the array being on a separate line, you'll need to tell typescript you want a stricter type on `arr`. The simplest way to do this is with `as const`, which tells typescript you won't be changing this array:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3] as const; // readonly [number, number, number]
const myNumber = _.sample(arr); // number
```

---

You can see the type definitions for `sample` here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/lodash/common/collection.d.ts#L1641 . The tuple case is handled by this type:

```
sample<T>(collection: readonly [T, ...T[]]): T;
```

And the array case is handled by this type:

```
sample<T>(collection: Dictionary<T> | NumericDictionary<T> | null | undefined): T | undefined;
```

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! What would be the best way to make TS understand that `number` is not undefined in this case:

`const arr = _.range(0, 1000);  const number = _.sample(arr);`

A type assertion or are there better solutions?